# Crystal Report / Sage X3 Custom Function

Tags: crystal-reports

I use CR2013 with SAGE X3 V7. A former coworker created a custom function to format phone numbers. We use this function in a lot of reports. We are migrating Sage X3 to a new version in a new server. Reports have been moved to this new server.

But when we print a report using this function from the new X3 version, we have this error code

```
 Message 1/3 : Erreur à l'ouverture du rapport: xxxxxxxxxx\ZARCCLIENT.rpt
- Message 2/3 : Echec du chargement du rapport
- Message 3/3 : Erreur dans le fichier ZARCCLIENT 6976_2964_{B35860BF-F698-4802-8025-B91607C6EBEF}.rpt :
Erreur dans la formule USR_Tel: 
'if ({BPADDRESS_USR.TEL_0} <> "") then ZFormatTelephoneFax ({BPADDRESS_USR.TEL_0}, {TABCOUNTRY_USR.TELFMT_0})
'
L'UFL u212com.dll qui implémente cette fonction est manquante.
```

I Installed CR2013 on the new server.
I copied the u212com.dll from the old to the new server and I types the following command following this instructions : [CrystalReports_QRCode_UFL](https://www.barcoderesource.com/CrystalReports_QRCode_UFL.shtml)

```
gacutil -i CRUFL_u212com.dll            

Regasm u212com.dll
```

but I have these errors codes

```
Échec de l'ajout de l'assembly au cache : Le module était censé contenir un manifeste de l'assembly.
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Échec de chargement de 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\u212com.dll', car ce n'est pas un assembly .NET valide
```

When I open a crystal report and I go in the formula workshop, I can't see any functions in the report custom function, on the new and on the old server.
I can't access the repository custom function, i have no user and password. And I don't think I have a Central Management Server installed.

When i create a function, in the old server, I can find my custom function in Functions/Additionnals functions/UFL COM and Net (u212.com.dll) if it can help.

So how can I use this custom function on my new server?
How can I see the custom function code in Crystal reports?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your u212com.dll is not .NET dll, but pure COM one? In that case you have to register it in cmd shell, using regsvr32:

```
regsvr32 u212com.dll
```

You need to run command prompt as administrator of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also tried this but I have the following error : The module "u212com.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "u212com.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.